# PHP echo strftime('%s'); returns -1, should be epoch time

Tags: php

I’m compiling PHP 7.4 from source on a self-managed Ubuntu 20.04 server with kernel `5.4.0-33-generic`. I am encountering an issue with obtaining the epoch time after compilation has completed successfully. This is the Bash command I am using:

```
php -r "echo strftime('%s');"
```

I expect the above to return epoch time (i.e. `1591628404` or thereabouts), but instead it returns `-1`.

In my A/B testing, running the above command on a vanilla Ubuntu LTS release with maintained `apt` packages returns the expected result. On the non-working system, all other [PHP strftime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) formats return correct/expected values.

A pure Bash epoch check (`date +%s`) returns the correct value.

It’s not clear to me whether the issue is with PHP compile/config setup, or operating system locale, or something else entirely.

I am grateful for any advice or feedback. Thank you for reading, and thank you for your time.

Edit: fixed typo curly inverted commas.

Edit: excerpt of results of `strace -o log.txt php -r "echo strftime('%s');"` suggested by @user1597430:

```
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
write(1, "-1", 2)                       = 2
close(2)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(0)                                = 0
```

Edit: results of `php -r "echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);"`: `LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=C;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C`

Comment: Is that closing `”` a typo?

Comment: try `strace` to debug the logic

Comment: `echo time();` was too difficult?

Comment: @kerbh0lz - typo in my OP, yes - fixed now - thank you. Terminal command that returns `-1` does not have typo.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - I am debugging an issue from a PHP CMS, I'm paring it back to exclude as much as possible, so not too difficult - existing code may change as a result.

Comment: @user1597430 - thank you, I'll look into that now.

Comment: Could it be something locale-related? If you do `php -r "echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);"`, what do you see?

Comment: @ChrisForrence - thank you. This is what I see: `LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=C;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C`

Answer (score 0):

A few words about debugging.

I suggest you to install `strace` and run the following command:

```
strace -o log.txt php -r "echo strftime('%s');"
```

You'll get a lot of debug info in your `log.txt` file. What you need is close to the end of file (right before `close(2)`, `close(1)` and `close(0)` instructions):

I can't reproduce your problem, but can show you what you should see when `strftime` works properly:

```
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3494, ...}) = 0
write(1, "1591665695", 10)              = 10
close(2)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(0)                                = 0
```

I guess, your output would reveal problems with your locale in `/etc/localtime`.

Comment: You should inspect your localtime file. It should be a symbolic link, which should point to a file (e.g. `/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York`).

Comment: Also, don't forget to check your logs, e.g. `dmesg | grep localtime` and `journalctl -r -b | grep localtime`. If your time is not configured properly, an operating system may inform you about that.

Comment: Thanks again, I greatly appreciate this. `/etc/localtime` symlinks to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC`. `dmesg | grep localtime` returns nothing. `journalctl -r -b | grep localtime` also returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this query to the php-general mailing list and received this response:

> PHP's strftime() is implemented on top of strftime(3) which is rather
>   system specific; the %s modifier isn't even required by POSIX.

While this isn't an answer to my question in the strictest sense, I'm posting here for completeness. Existing code has been modified to take account of systems returning `-1` values.